# Antlr4 - matching an identifier as a single token

Tags: python, parsing, antlr, antlr4, lexer

```
BLOCK_COMMENT : '/*' .*? '*/' -> skip;
EOL_COMMENT : '//' ~[\r\n]* -> skip;
WS: [ \n\t\r]+ -> skip;

program: usingDirectives? EOF;

usingDirectives: usingDirective+;

usingDirective: USING
        fullyQualifiedType
        (usingAlias | USING_ALL)?
        END;

USING: 'using';

fullyQualifiedType: identifier (DOT identifier)*;

identifier: (LETTER | UNDERSCORE)
        (LETTER | DIGIT | UNDERSCORE)*;

DOT: '.';

usingAlias: AS identifier;

USING_ALL: '.*';

AS: 'as';

END: ';';

LETTER: [a-zA-Z];

DIGIT: [0-9];

UNDERSCORE: '_';
```

This is my grammar.

```
using IO.Console.Print as Print;
using IO.Console; // same as using IO.Console as Console;
using IO.Console.*;
```

This is my test data.

The grammar works as intended, but each letter in an identifier becomes a single token, which is a bit useless.

If I try to make identifier a lexer rule (IDENTIFIER), then I get the following error, when running the test:

```
line 1:23 extraneous input 'as' expecting {'.', '.*', 'as', ';'}
```

Even if I try to have IDENTIFIER be only [a-zA-Z], without subrules, the same happens.

If it matters, I'm using Python3 as the target language.
Please point out any other rookie mistakes as well, as this is my first project using Antlr. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right now you tell your lexer to yield a collection of characters suitable for a identifier instead of a identifier as a whole. Following simplified grammar(lexer and parser) should work for you:

```
grammar test;

root
    : identifier*;

identifier
    : IdentifierChars;

IdentifierChars
    : [a-zA-Z0-9_]+;

WhiteSpace
   : [ \r\n\t]+ -> skip;
```

here is a sample Java code i used to check:

```
    InputStream input = IntegrationMain.class.getResourceAsStream("test.txt");
    ANTLRInputStream inputStream = new ANTLRInputStream(input);
    TokenSource tokenSource = new testLexer(inputStream);
    CommonTokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(tokenSource);
    testParser parser = new testParser(tokenStream);
    testParser.RootContext root = parser.root();

    root.identifier().forEach(identifier -> System.out.println(identifier.getText()));
```

and here is the result from stdout:

```
abc
a0bc
a_bc
```

Comment: Thanks. I took your advice and simplified the grammar. Also, it turns out that my basic understanding of how Antlr works was lacking. Once I figured out that rule order was important and that lexer rules are all evaluated before any parser rules, it all started making a lot of sense

Comment: glad it helped solving your problem, you are welcome.